# Wrong output in large inputs

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree

Please help me out with this problem: https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1131/

I'm getting the wrong output for large values.
The algorithm is: computing the height of the left subtree and the right subtree by using an arbitrary node.
Thank you :)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define int long long int
using namespace std; 
 
 
bool visited[200005] = {false}; 
 
vector<vector<int>> vect(200005);
 
int height(int n) {
    int m = 0, t=-1; 
    visited[n] = true; 
    for(auto x : vect[n]) {
        if(visited[x] == false) {
            t = height(x);
            if(m < t) 
                m = t; 
        }
    }
    return m+1;
}
 
int treeDiameter(int n) {
    int m1=0, m2=0, t=0;
    visited[n] = true;  
    for(auto x : vect[n]) {
        t = height(x); 
        if(t > m1) {
            m2 = m1; 
            m1 = t; 
        }
        else if(t > m2) 
            m2 = t; 
    }
    return m1 + m2;
}
 
int32_t main() {
    int n, m=999999; 
    cin >> n;
    n--;
    if(n > 1) {
        while(n--) {
            int a, b; 
            cin >> a >> b; 
            vect[a].push_back(b);
            vect[b].push_back(a); 
            if(a < m) m = a; 
        }
        // cout << m;
        cout << treeDiameter(m); 
    } else cout << 0 << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Have a look at how to make a [mcve]. Might be worth looking into integer overflow from the looks of it. Have you tried using a debugger to see where/when things go wrong?

Comment: Dear, I think that's too monotonous to debug such a large value. Thus, I thought that better to avoid it, rest I am checking "minimal reproducible example". And, I'll come back to you.

Comment: *I think that's too monotonous to debug such a large value* This makes no sense. Just learn to use a debugger properly. It will save you more time then you can imagine in the future. Also, you should consider adjusting your tone young one.

Comment: @super, I think whatever I am able to understand from the link you provided, I already did that, from writing "Restart from scratch" to "Divide and conquer". Still the same. @_@

Comment: you may use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library to overcome the number limit. but since u r memory bounded. It is best to work within the given 512MB memory.